# Gatsby - GraphQL image undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to use Gatsby Image to lazy load images into CSS grid. I keep getting the error - "Cannot read property 'person' of undefined".

I'm not sure why/what I'm doing wrong as it should all work/the queries work in graphiql.

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"


const Portfolio = ( {data} ) => {

    return(

        <div>
            <Img fluid={data.person.childImageSharp.fluid} />
        </div>

    )

}


export const query = graphql`
  query{
    person: file(relativePath: { eq: "people-five.png" }){
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 1000){
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
}

export default Portfolio
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing backtick in your graphql query

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const Portfolio = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Img fluid={data.person.childImageSharp.fluid} />
    </div>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    person: file(relativePath: { eq: "people-five.png" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default Portfolio
```

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)